# Estou com dificuldade de entender a lógica

Tags: javascript

Problema:

> Crie uma função fontes() que receba como entrada uma frase qualquer. Em seguida, escreva no corpo da página esta
>   frase usando fontes de tamanhos diferentes (do 1 ao 7). Para isto, você deve fazer um laço que irá repetir a seguinte TAG,
>   alterando apenas o atributo "size":

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender a lógica?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Qual parte não funcionou? Em que característica está com problemas (fazer um laço? criar tags? setar o tamanho da fonte? criar a função?)?

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Já tentou algo? Se sim coloque o código, se não tente que é só irá conseguir algo tentando e errando!

Comment: Olá @user8919, bem vindo ao [so.pt]. Recomendo uma leitura na [help] em especial no tópico [ask].

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um exercício de lógica o qual, aparentemente, o usuário não tem sequer um código-base para ser auxiliado. Quer apenas o "peixe pronto".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lógica é:

- crie uma função chamada `fontes` que receba como entrada uma frase qualquer

Aqui fica um exemplo minimalista de função

```
function fontes(frase){
    alert(frase); // só para verificar
};
```

- escreva no corpo da página esta frase usando fontes de tamanhos diferentes (do 1 ao 7)

Aqui precisa de "ir buscar" o corpo da página e guardar numa variável:

```
var corpo = document.querySelector('body'); // ou outro elemento que queira
```

- Para isto, você deve fazer um laço que irá repetir a seguinte TAG, alterando apenas o atributo "size"

Ora um `for` loop típico é

```
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
   // fazer qq coisa
}
```

Neste caso, dentro do loop tem de mudar o css/style do texto. Aqui surge um passo que não está defenido na pergunta: como empacotar a frase? com uma `div`, `<p>` ou `<span>`? ecolha.

Se usar um `<p>` o código dentro do loop poderia ser:

```
corpo.innerHTML += '<p style="font-size: '+i+'em;">'+frase+'</p>';
```

### Exemplo:  http://jsfiddle.net/r6VY4/

Código final:

```
function fontes(frase) {
    var corpo = document.querySelector('body');
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        corpo.innerHTML += '<p style="font-size: ' + i + 'em;">' + frase + '</p>';
    }
};
fontes('Olá mundo!');
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
     function fontes(frase) {
    var corpo = document.querySelector('body');
    var frase = prompt("Digite uma frase","");
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        corpo.innerHTML += '<p style="font-size: ' + i + 'em;">' + frase + '</p>';
    }
};
fontes();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
Me faltou material e exemplo pra fazer por isso não tinha nem um ponto de partida . Consegui entender e o que mais precisava era a fórmula do for !

Comment: @user8919, se resolveu o problema pode escolher uma das respostas como correta. Note que no código que colocou no comentário o seu `for` faz um loop a menos. Ou começa em `1` e faz `<8` ou então `<=7`, como você tem (`var i = 1; i < 7; i++`) ele vai fazer somente 6 loops.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar **N** elementos, mas como não especificou, vou deixar em exemplo com o elemento `font`:

```
function fontes(frase){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 7; i++){ // laço para criar os elementos
      var e = document.createElement('font'); // cria um elemento font
      e.setAttribute("size",i); // altera o atributo size
      e.innerHTML = frase; // adiciona a frase no elemento
      document.body.appendChild(e); // adiciona no body
    }
}
fontes('Stackoverflow '); // chama a função
```

**[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq9fB/)**